# cloning a repository in gitkraken from url ssh invalid

Tags: linux, git, gitkraken

I'm quite new to Linux and I have some trouble using GitKraken (in Windows I use SourceTree). I want to clone a repository that is on my NAS. Unfortunately, when I try to clone it says: "Configured SSH key is invalid. Please confirm that it is properly associated with your Git provider". In Preferences>Authentication I have checked (default) Use Local SHH agent.
If I clone the rep from the terminal with git clone command it asks for the password and everything is ok.
Any suggestion?
Alex

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message in my GitKraken.
I followed carefully all the steps of "Set up SSH for Git on XXX" (Windows in my case) and managed to make it work.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html

Not sure it exactly applies to your case, but maybe it can guide you to the right direction.